# Trying to create resource group using New-AzureRmResourceGroup cmdlet in azure webjob

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-resource-manager, webjob

I have a working azure arm powershell scripts to create a new virtual machine and it's working fine in cloud service but when I am trying to execute in azure webjob, I am getting following Error :

New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -Location $location

New-AzureRmResourceGroup : The Win32 internal error "The handle is invalid" 
0x6 occurred while setting character attributes for the console output buffer. 
Contact Microsoft Customer Support Services.
At D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\webjob\v43suxvk.lln\testDrives\WindowsServer201
2\provision.ps1:17 char:1
+ New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -Location $location
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroup], Host 
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureResou 
   rceGroupCommand

so how can I run arm powershell scripts in webjobs?